# get zero counts in sql query

Tags: sql, count, zero

This topic has been treated before, but I still can not find my solution. 
I am counting the times a service has been on/off.
If the service has never been off (e.g. for id = 7182), then status == 'off' does not exist in the table for that service.

How can I get the counts off==0 as shown in the example below ? 
I have highlighted examples of the rows that I need and can not get displayed.

Thanks a lot in advance,

PS: I have been playing with coalesce, but no luck or don't now how to use it properly.

```
SELECT id, status, count(*)
from history 
group by id, status
order by id, status; 

  id  | status | count 
------+--------+-------
 7182 | on     |    50
 7182 | off    |     0 <-- Not shown in the output as there is no id=7182 with status=off
 7183 | on     |    50
 7183 | off    |     0 <-- Not shown in the output as there is no id=7183 with status=off
 7184 | on     |    49
 7184 | off    |     1
```

Comment: Sorry, its not clear which count you need it. Can you please elaborate little more

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, status, count(*)
from history 
group by id, status
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'OFF', 0
from history
where id not in (select id from history where status = 'OFF')
order by id, status;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, now the count = 0 are not displayed, and you want to get it in the result. Just give it a try:

```
SELECT id, status, count(*) as c
from history 
group by id, status
having c >= 0
order by id, status;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `conditional sum` and get the on/off count as

```
select
id,
sum( case when status = 'on' then 1 else 0 end)  as on_count,
sum( case when status = 'off' then 1 else 0 end ) as off_count
from history
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Some id/status combinations are missing in the table, but you want to see them. The solution is to create them with a cross join:

```
select i.id, s.status, count(*)
from (select distinct id from history) as i
cross join (select distinct status from history) as s
left join history h on h.id = i.id and h.status = s.status
group by i.id, s.status
order by i.id, s.status;
```

BTW: It is a bad idea to name a column ID when it's not the unique ID for records in the table.